# can someone help me understand why VS Code is throwing this error?

Tags: visual-studio-code, bulma

I am not sure why VS code is throwing an error here.
I have removed all CSS extensions and added the HTML CSS Support extension back in.
I am using Bulma to develop an angular project.

any thoughts?

[image]

in case anyone wants to try it in their environment.

````
```
.heading-section {
    background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(2,228,171), rgb(74,215,240));
   
    padding:100px;

    h1.title{
        font-weight:bold;
        color:white;
        text-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(black, 0.12);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't valid CSS syntax.

Comment: with Angular and Bulma, the video I was following had both .heading-section and h1.title the same color.  they were recognized as objects, but mine is not.

Comment: Was it a CSS file or Sass/Less? I'm not familiar with Bulma, but from a quick glance through the documentation I don't see anything about nested selectors.

Comment: it has both a sass and css component to it.  I have added them to the angular.json as             "styles": [
              "../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css" , 
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],

Comment: No, the file in the video where they wrote the code you're following.

Comment: and style.css /* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass";

Comment: the video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvWxMQ_Zios at the 16:30 minute mark

Comment: Notice the extension on the file they're working on, `.scss`. That's why you're getting the error, you're trying to use Sass syntax in a CSS file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229178/discussion-between-roger-i-and-john-montgomery).

Comment: Yes, my ng generate component is creating CSS files instead of SCSS.  I changed the name and it worked, thanks for your time. please add as answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code is working correctly here.

The nested selector syntax you're trying to use is a feature of [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/), so trying to use it in a regular CSS file won't work. You have two options here:

1. Change the extension of your file from `.css` to `.scss`, assuming your project is set up to handle it (which Angular is by default). This is the option that was used in [the video you linked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvWxMQ_Zios).
2. Change your syntax to work in CSS, like this:

```css
.heading-section {
    background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(2,228,171), rgb(74,215,240));
   
    padding:100px;
}
.heading-section h1.title{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(black, 0.12);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **invalid syntax in css** maybe the tutorial is made in scss you should apply the title class in h1

```
<h1 class="title"> My title </h1>
```

And then use it your css like:

```
.title{

}
```

Or try to add the live sass extension to your vs code, and then change the file extension to .scss, turn on the compiler,save and you are good to go with this syntax.
[Live sass compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass)